# For which $\alpha$ do limits for $F(a,b)= \int_A||x||_2^\alpha dx$ exist?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have a function $$F(a,b)= \int_A||x||_2^\alpha dx$$ where $||x||_2$ denotes the euclidean norm and $A = \{x\in \mathbb R^2: a\leq ||x||_2 \le b\}$ and I would like to find all $\alpha$, for which the limits $\lim_{a \to 0} F(a,1)$, $\lim_{b\to \infty} F(1,b)$ and $\lim_{a\to 0}\lim_{b\to \infty} F(a,b)$ exist.

I have already solved a similar excercise for the one dimensional case, but I do not know how to proceed with this one. Since this is two dimensional, I am having troubles knowing what to do. So far, all I have learned about multidimensional integration is Fubini's theorem. The main problem I am having here is that I do not know how I would even integrate the above term, for a given $\alpha$. I know that I can use double integration for "square" intervals, but in this case $A$ is a circle, which confuses me even further. What can I do here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use polar coordinates. $dx = r \, dr \, d\theta$.

Comment: @Chappers I thought this might be a way, but is that the only way? Is there another way? Otherwise I will have to give this a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start this problem, you want to change your basis. As you said, you're integrating over an annulus (a flat donut, like a circle with an inner circle cut out). In this case treating the plane with $x$ and $y$ is messy, the natural system to use is polar coordinates. If $u$ is some point in the plane expressed with polar coordinates, $\Vert u \Vert_2$ is simply equal to the radial component of $u$. The integral becomes:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}||x||_2^\alpha r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\phi = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}r^{1+\alpha}\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\phi$$
This is because you first want to integrate over the set of radial values for each $x$, and then the set of angular values. (Just like you would integrate over $x$ and then $y$.) You'll also see an extra $r$ that seems to have appeared out of nowhere. This is a factor that always appears in an integral when you convert from cartesian to polar, and intuitively occurs because if you integrate over a ring with $k$ times the radius of another ring, you expect there to be $k$ times as many "points" you're summing.

Now you'll realise you can integrate this: Assuming everything is well defined in this case, you get
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{a}^{b}r^{1+\alpha}\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\phi &= \frac{1}{2+\alpha}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\Big[r^{2+\alpha}\Big]_{a}^{b}\mathrm{d}\phi\\
&= \frac{1}{2+\alpha}\int_{0}^{2\pi}b^{2+\alpha}-a^{2+\alpha}\mathrm{d}\phi\\
&= \frac{2\pi}{2+\alpha}\big(b^{2+\alpha}-a^{2+\alpha}\big)
\end{align*}

Now that you know how to integrate it, I'm sure you'll be fine with the actual questions! Usually the best way to first learn calculus of this nature is through physics (especially electromagnetism).

Comment: No problem! If any part of it doesn't make sense, try drawing a picture. You'll see why circles and other related shapes (such as this one) are also called "polar rectangles".